# View a sharepoint list inside a webpart SharePoint2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I've developed this webpart on sharepoint 2010 that displays some query results in a simple grid, the customer want to extend this to a sharepoint list to leverage the sharepoint list functionality.
is there a simple straightforward approach to show the results in a list inside a webpart?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ListViewByQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.listviewbyquery%28v=office.14%29.aspx) control within your webpart.